# How to enable strict type parsing for jackson?

Tags: java, jax-rs, jackson

Jackson 1.9.9 is somewhat inconsistent in what it parses into scalar values (bool, int, string). Any array or object type fails but you can put any scalar type into a string. For bool 0 and not 0 are mapped to false/true. int attributes accept only numbers.

```
public class Foo { public String s; public boolean b; public int i; }

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
System.out.println(mapper.readValue("{\"s\":\"abc\"}", Foo.class).s); // "abc"
System.out.println(mapper.readValue("{\"s\":true}", Foo.class).s); // "true"
System.out.println(mapper.readValue("{\"s\":123}", Foo.class).s); // "123"
System.out.println(mapper.readValue("{\"b\":123}", Foo.class).b); // true
System.out.println(mapper.readValue("{\"b\":0}", Foo.class).b); // false
System.out.println(mapper.readValue("{\"b\":\"abc\"}", Foo.class).b); // fails with JsonMappingException
System.out.println(mapper.readValue("{\"i\":\"abc\"}", Foo.class).i); // fails with JsonMappingException
System.out.println(mapper.readValue("{\"i\":true}", Foo.class).i); // fails with JsonMappingException
System.out.println(mapper.readValue("{\"s\":[]}", Foo.class).s); // fails with JsonMappingException
System.out.println(mapper.readValue("{\"s\":{}}", Foo.class).s); // fails  with JsonMappingException
System.out.println(mapper.readValue("{\"b\":[]}", Foo.class).b); // fails with JsonMappingException
System.out.println(mapper.readValue("{\"b\":{}}", Foo.class).b); // fails  with JsonMappingException
System.out.println(mapper.readValue("{\"i\":[]}", Foo.class).i); // fails with JsonMappingException
System.out.println(mapper.readValue("{\"i\":{}}", Foo.class).i); // fails  with JsonMappingException
```

Is there a **strict mode** for Jackson so that I get an error if someone passes for example a boolean value into a String attribute?

I am using this in a JAX-RS project and this makes error reporting based on exceptions thrown by Jackson somewhat difficult since I get most of the errors but not all of them. I would like to avoid getting a raw ObjectNode and checking everything manually. If a caller passes a boolean for a string then I would like to tell him that since this is most likely a programming error.

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, if you come across this much later, like I did, [ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/MapperFeature.html#ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS) will help somewhat by reducing the number of conversions that Jackson will do you your behalf, although it's far from a complete strict mode; many type coercions will still be performed, but some will be prevented. The linked documentation gets into some of the details.

Comment: Caution: Tthis will only help for bools and ints. If your POJO has a String field, and the input JSON has a number/bool, those will still be coerced into a String without any exception during deserialization

Answer (score 2):

Jackson data-binding has grown over time to accept more automatic coercions, and although there are some features (DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_NULL_FOR_PRIMITIVES) to enforce stricter checks, not many have been requested.

Given this, your best is to register custom `JsonDeserializer` for types you want to be stricter on, like `boolean`/`Boolean`. You can implement stricter checks there.

In addition, you can request feature(s) for stricter limitations: I think this does make sense for some use cases, esp. if looser conversions can hide real problems.

Comment: How the default JSON solution for Java can be that much ill-behaved?

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph what you consider ill-behaved is considered by others to be very useful for inter-operability, given that many programming languages lack actual boolean type, or for some reason or another use values other than JSON `true`/`false` for similar concept. Strict failure is something _some_ users want, but something many others would find cumbersome and, well, ill-behaved.

Comment: Consideration is subjective. [Implicit casting considered harmful](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/284937/why-cant-there-be-any-implicit-conversions) long ago. Whatever some users think on usefulness of implicit casts, they do result in errors. For a language without a boolean type (or with several boolean types) explicit conversion annotation is the only correct way to go. The problem with Jackson is that it inconsistently implements a few of those conversions, otherwise requiring (de)serializer for the whole type, and that's the reason I call it ill-behaved.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph Yes, your and mine opinions are subjective, and a single article claiming something (like implicit casting) is just one more person's opinion. As to Jackson, coercion is done at databinding level: at streaming parser, tokens and types are exposed exactly as is -- but at databinding user _specifically expects_ `boolean` as target type, so coercion is justified. If so, there are just 2 ways to go: either (a) do what is being requested or (b) be a jerk and claim that can not be done. Some libs do that. Others not. There is no right answer.

Comment: Yep, `"4a"+6` may either be a `6.16667` _as requested_ or a programming language may _be a jerk_ and reject it. Surely there's _no right answer_. Did you try getting out of bubble of ignorance to find hundreds of such articles and some scientific literature on type theory?

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph where did you get `"4a"+6`? Do you need to resort to inventing stuff now? This is not relevant to discussion; you are merely building a straw man argument to try to support for dubious claim of your PERSONAL preferences being correct answers, universally accepted as such. I don't even know why you feel compelled to try type theory argument; trying to complicate relatively simple question of type coercions between data models.

Comment: @StaxMan You're right in JavaScript, but in Java this is plain wrong.

Comment: @Agent_L Java, as a language, does have stricter type rules for its own processing, but given that json is widely used between systems where Java is only used on one side (like Java service, Python client) it does not serve as definition of how coercions or conversions should work in my opinion. Originally coercions for booleans, in particular, did start with Perl clients' inability to deal with booleans (sending `0` and `1` if I recall).

Comment: @StaxMan It's just hiding errors. A violation of principle of failing early and in the long run often costing more than it saves. The question is not about language-abstract json specs, it's about concrete, Java example, where 0 doesn't cast to boolean. Had we've been talking about Perl client, I'd agree with you. The problem is getting some recognition, finally, as eg. default Swift parser crashes at such (previously considered minor) discrepancies.

Comment: @Agent_L I do not see relevance of your repeated statement "but that's not how it works in Java" -- I have not claimed it does. I also did not argue that Perl, Python or such semantics should be used. But I do maintain that there is nothing fundamentally wrong in library trying its best to map different representations into compatible values. But at this point I don't think discussion is leading anywhere here. For what it is worth, I am aware of and have sympathy for desire for alternate behavior. Challenge comes in how various coercion options should be configured.