# Prevent Primitive To String Conversion in SpringBoot / Jackson

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

We have written a Springboot Rest Service, it internally uses Jackson for Serialisation / deserialisation of Json input / output of Rest APIs.

We do not want type conversion of primitives to / from String for API input / output.

We have disabled String to Primitive conversion using

`spring.jackson.mapper.allow-coercion-of-scalars=false`

But Primitive to String conversion is still being allowed.

e.g.

`"name": 123,`

from API is still deserialised to `"123"`, Java data type of `name` is `String` here.

We have gone through [Customize the Jackson ObjectMapper](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper) section of Spring Docs and does not look like there is anything in those enums that can be used.

Is there a way to achieve this without writing a custom ObjectMapper / Deserializer?

Comment: Take a look on my answer to this question [Restrict string data type to only string types for request body in Spring boot 2.4 (Jackson)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65461398/51591). You need to register custom deserialiser which throws exception for scalar values.

Comment: @MichałZiober : Your solution works, although with slight modification. ```token.isBoolean()
                || token.isNumeric()
                || !token.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("VALUE_STRING")``` Since String itself is a scalar, your solution as-is does not work for any Scalar type, including Strings. If you can post your comment as answer, can accept it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We did not find any config property that achieves this, finally went with the solution posted by [Michał Ziober](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51591/micha%C5%82-ziober).

```
package xyz;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken;

import java.io.IOException;

public class StrictStringDeserializer extends StringDeserializer {
    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        JsonToken token = p.currentToken();
        if (token.isBoolean()
                || token.isNumeric()
                || !token.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("VALUE_STRING")) {
            ctxt.reportInputMismatch(String.class, "%s is not a `String` value!", token.toString());
            return null;
        }
        return super.deserialize(p, ctxt);
    }
}
```

POJO Class

```
public class XyzAbc {

    // ...
    @JsonDeserialize(using = StrictStringDeserializer.class)
    private String name;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I'm glad to see you found a solution and improved implementation. I did not have time to post this as an answer and check your proposal. You can always upvote other my answer if it was helpful.